# How to do many-to-many mapping in jaxb using orm

Tags: orm, jaxb, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to use jaxb to autogenerate some hibernate mapped classes that contain a many-to-many relationship between Authors and Books. Database is postgres. What I am trying to achieve is Authors.java and Books.java that look like below:

Goal: Books.java

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Author.class, cascade = {
    CascadeType.ALL
    }, mappedBy="books")
    public List<Author> getAuthors() {
    if (authors == null) {
        authors = new ArrayList<AUTHOR>();
    }
    return this.authors;
    }
```

Here is bindings.xjb (parts of it)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.0"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:hj="http://hyperjaxb3.jvnet.org/ejb/schemas/customizations"
xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="hj orm">

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="types.xsd"
    node="/xs:schema">

    <jaxb:bindings
            node="xs:complexType[@name='author']//xs:element[@name='books']">
                   <hj:many-to-many>
                         <orm:join-table name="AUTHORS_BOOKS">
                                <orm:join-column name="aid" />
                                <orm:inverse-join-column name="bid"/>
                         </orm:join-table>
                   </hj:many-to-many>
     </jaxb:bindings>

    <jaxb:bindings
            node="xs:complexType[@name='book']//xs:element[@name='authors']">
                   <hj:many-to-many name="authors" mapped-by="books">
                       <hj:cascade>
                       <hj:cascade-persist/>
                       </hj:cascade>
                   </hj:many-to-many>
     </jaxb:bindings>


    <jaxb:bindings
        node="xs:complexType[@name='author']//xs:element[@name='aid']">
        <hj:id>
            <orm:generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
        </hj:id>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <jaxb:bindings
        node="xs:complexType[@name='book']//xs:element[@name='bid']">
        <hj:id>
            <orm:generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
        </hj:id>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</bindings>
```

Here is types.xsd (parts of it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://catapult.jieddo.mil/feeds/domain"
xmlns:tns="http://catapult.jieddo.mil/feeds/domain"   
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:complexType name="author">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="books" type="tns:book" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1000"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="book">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="authors" type="tns:author" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1000"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Using the above bindings and xsd the files I am generating are shown below.

Current: Authors.java

```
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Book.class, cascade = {
    CascadeType.ALL
})
@JoinTable(name = "AUTHORS_BOOKS", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "aid")
}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "bid")
})
public List<Book> getBooks() {
    if (books == null) {
        books = new ArrayList<Book>();
    }
    return this.books;
}
```

Current: Books.java

```
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Author.class, cascade = {
    CascadeType.ALL
}, mappedBy="books")
@JoinTable(name = "BOOK_AUTHORS_BOOK", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_BOOK_ID")
}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_AUTHOR_ID")
})
public List<Author> getAuthors() {
    if (authors == null) {
        authors = new ArrayList<AUTHOR>();
    }
    return this.authors;
}
```

In the current Book.java I don't think the @JoinTable notation should be there (the table name is wrong too). I keep running into the lazy initialization error if I make the fetch lazy or leave it undeclared in the bindings.xjb

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

if I make the fetch="EAGER" then I get the following error:

org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

And I think I am getting those issues because something in my mapping is goofy. Any Ideas on whats going on here?